# What is System.Runtime.ActionItem?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it part of ThreadPool API? Cannot find it on MSDN. It looks like a Threading API, with just `ActionItem.Schedule` method exposed.

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/16m6q9k.jpg

Comment: Right click on the class, go to definition.  That will at least tell you if its some custom component someone made and erroneously tossed into a System namespace.

Comment: If you right click and use go to definition, what assembly is it defined in?

Comment: It is an internal abstract helper class for WCF.  Looks like you are peering inside the framework code, ChannelHandler is an internal class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an abstract class that schedules invocation of delegates. It's also internal to the System.Runtime.DurableInstancing assembly and should never be used by your code. If you don't find MSDN documentation for a class, that's usually a good sign that you don't need to use it directly.